# Unable to access exported state variable from custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, material-ui

I have a custom hook for light/dark mode using MUI, it exports a state variable which I then pass to MUI's createTheme to tell it what theme to use. However I can't access the state variable outside of my hook, getting undefined when I console.log it. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I took this code directly from the MUI documentation.

Hook code:

```
const useProvideColorTheme = () => {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState<PaletteMode>('light');

    const colorMode = useMemo(
        () => ({
            toggleColorMode: () => {
                setMode((prevMode: PaletteMode) =>
                    prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light',
                );
            },
        }),
        [],
    );

    return {
        colorMode,
        mode,
        setMode,
    };
}
```

in `_app.tsx`

```
import { ProvideColorTheme, useColorTheme } from '../lib/hooks/useColorTheme';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';


const getDesignTokens = (mode) => {...}


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const appTheme = useColorTheme();
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(getDesignTokens(appTheme.mode)), [appTheme.mode]);
  return (
    <hook>
      <hook>
        <hook>
          <ProvideColorTheme>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <hook>
                <hook>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </hook>
              </hook>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </ProvideColorTheme>
        </hook>
      </hook>
    </hook>
  );
}
```

MUI Versions

"@mui/styles": "^5.8.0"

"@mui/material": "^5.6.4"

React/Next.js Versions

"react": "18.1.0"

"react-dom": "18.1.0"

"next": "12.1.6"

Comment: Did you mean to call `useProvideColorTheme`?

Comment: You arent calling your hook in the function MyAPP you are using useColorTheme which is something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access it inside your file because that app doesn't exist within `ProvideColorTheme`. Technically `useColorTheme` before it gets rendered within the app. This is why your `MyApp` component needs to live within it.

I would recommend making a CustomProviders file which wrap your app. Something like I have below will work.

```js
const AppProviders = () => {
   return (
      <ProvideColorTheme>
          <MyApp />
      </ProvideColorTheme>
   )
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const appTheme = useColorTheme();
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(getDesignTokens(appTheme.mode)), [appTheme.mode]);
  return (
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
     </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

This is the issue with providers and you will often get put into 'Provider Hell' where you have dozens of providers that all need each other.